# Openlayers WFS how to find all necessary parameters

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I would like to add WFS to my map. I know the example on openlayers.org but I have problem with my custom url

```
     const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function (extent) {
    return (
      'https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/DanePomiaroweLidarKRON86/WFS/Skorowidze?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeatures&typename=gugik:SkorowidzeDanychPomiarowychLIDAR2022&outputFormat=application/gml+xml&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' +
      extent.join(',') +
      ',EPSG:3857'
      );
    },
    
  strategy: bboxStrategy,

});
```

The problem how to identify all the parameters such: typename, output Format, EPSG ect from only url?

https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/DanePomiaroweLidarEVRF2007/WFS/Skorowidze?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Can someone help me to prepare correct url for openlayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format must be `WFS` as the service does not support `application/json` output.  `request` should be `GetFeature` (not `GetFeatures`).  `version` is also required (`1.1.0` is the WFS format default).

This works for me but the service does not support CORS so a proxy or browser override will be needed https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-hgwkvv?file=/main.js

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new WFS(),
  url: function (extent) {
    return (
      'https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/DanePomiaroweLidarEVRF2007/WFS/Skorowidze?SERVICE=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=gugik:SkorowidzDanychPomiarowychLIDAR2022&' +
      'srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
      'bbox=' +
      extent.join(',') +
      ',EPSG:3857'
    );
  },
  strategy: bboxStrategy,
});
```